# Based on articles taxonomy and branch selection we are differentiating the taxonomies for different branches

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Based on articles taxonomy  and branch selection we are differentiating the taxonomies for different branches.

I created one taxonomy per one page
         just like

```
       section 1
        sub section 1
       section 2
        sub section 2


    In one page  there are many different section is there,

    first you created article i.e. hide test

    select taxonomy as like above
    after select section of the page

    taxonomy will be display only in that section of the page  
    Case1:

    We are creation one article
    While creation I selected Taxonomy “section 1 ” and one page section “one”
    This taxonomy is available only "one"  section only.

    Case2:
    We are creation one article
    While creation I am not  selected Taxonomy “section 1” and one page section “two”. I selected the some other category
    Display another category in this two  section.

    Case3:
    We are creatinog one article
    While creation I am selected Taxonomy “section 1 ” and one page section “one”,”two”.
    "hide test" will display in two branches.
```